# Outlook 2013 : remove list of CC email in content of reply all message

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm working with some 20-people-discuss-without-group-mail threads. When I reply to all with just 1 sentence, the mail content will be like below. How can I configure Outlook to not include the CC list in reply to all mail content?

Thanks in advance!

[image: useless CC list in mail content]

Comment: Maybe email is not the best communication method. Have you considered Slack, or Kakao (smartphone messaging app), or even Facebook messenger.

Comment: my company use Outlook with Exchange as an ONLY way to communication! (beside is real-time chatting tool like Lync)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an automated way or an Outlook setting that can accomplish this, but if you're replying-all to a message and just want the reply to go to everyone in the To: list but not the CC: list, you can just delete all the entries in the CC list.  Just click in front of the first name, hit CTRL-End (or CTRL-Shift-End), then Delete.

Comment: misunderstanding :(  I will update the question to be more meaningful after work, my Company proxy blocked Imgur :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually remove that TO list manually when you reply to the e-mail.

Or you can set your Outlook to not include the reply:

In Outlook 2013, File > Options > Mail > When replying to a message: "Do not include the original message"

[image]

Comment: I need the original message, but don't want to include the CC list